# Java HtmlUnit unable to fetch an element

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

While I am trying to fetch data from a particular tag, I am unable to get it even after 60 seconds of wait.

Here is the element with the xpath using inspect

[image: Here is the element with the xpath using inspect]

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JSoupTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "www.mywebsite.com";
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        driver.get(url);
        String path = "//*[@id=\"appContainer\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div";
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(path)));
        WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.className(path));
        System.out.println(webElement.getText());
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //*[@id="appContainer"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div
```

If I remove the wait then I am getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //*[@id="appContainer"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div
```

Comment: Try enable JavaScript for the driver

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.className(path));
```

You are looking by **class** instead of by **xpath**.

Also, it is worth noting that the **until** method already returns the element, so you don't need to find the element again:

```
WebElement webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(path)));
```